# I give up... gnome + xscreensaver

Tags: gnome-screensaver

I've got Ubuntu 14.04 for a short time, but there's a problem that really gets onto my nerves. Yes, it's the screensaver. I really don't mind it running but it is just impossible to watch anything on my laptop when screen dims after 10 mins. I've read all (I think) posts and problem solving advices online, however without success. I've removed gnome via terminal command and installed xscreensaver, which I set up to fade after such time to give me plenty to watch a movie. No luck... the screen still fades after 10 mins even though terminal tells me that gnome does not exist anymore.

Any ideas? I'm out of any now...

PS. On my previous versions of Ubuntu (10,11 and 12) there were no problems of this nature whatsoever.

Many thanks

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy gnome-screensaver`?

Answer (score 1):

Click on system settings in the launcher. Click brightness and lock. Change the time, you probably want never.

Comment: Jeez, this is truly embarrassing, but I checked "never" in PowerManagement. Thank you ever so much for clarifying my error.... it is all warking good now.

Comment: @PavelDoodeck: Don't thank him! **;-)** If you like the answer, just click the little grey ☑ under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green. This means "[yes, this answer is correct](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)"!